# Why do i get a segmentation fault because of my mutex_lock?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I am making a program that solves the dining philosophers problem and i get a segmentation fault when i try to lock my mutex. I am not allowed to use global variables so i have to kinda move my mutexes around with pointers, i feel like the way i do it is pretty janky and i'm kinda lost in my own code. here's the important functions

```
# include <string.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <pthread.h>
# include <sys/time.h>

typedef struct s_philo
{
    int                 n_philo;        //* number of philosophers
    int                 time_to_die;    //* time to die in ms
    int                 time_to_eat;    //* time to eat in ms
    int                 time_to_sleep;  //* time to sleep in ms
    int                 need_eat;       //* number of times each philosopher must eat
    u_int64_t           start_time;     //* time when the simulation starts
}   t_philo;

typedef struct s_data
{
    pthread_mutex_t     *left_fork;     //* pointer to the left fork
    pthread_mutex_t     *right_fork;    //* pointer to the right fork
    u_int64_t           last_eaten;     //* time when the philosopher last ate
    t_philo             *philo;         //* links to the philo struct
    int                 id;             //* id of the philosopher
    int                 dead;           //* 1 if the philosopher is dead
    int                 is_eating;      //* 1 if the philosopher is eating
    int                 n_eat;          //* number of times the philosopher has eaten
}   t_data;

u_int64_t   get_time(void);                                                             //* returns the time in ms
int         ft_usleep(useconds_t time);                                                 //* sleeps for time ms
int         ft_atoi(const char *str);                                                   //* converts a string to an int
void        init_philo(t_philo *philo, int argc, char **argv);                          //* initializes the philo struct
void        init_data(t_data *data, t_philo *philo, int id);                            //* initializes the data struct
void        *routine(void *vdata);                                                      //* routine of the philosophers
void        *monitor(void *vdata);                                                      //* monitors the philosophers (exemples: death)
int         ft_eat(void *vdata);                                                        //* eat function
int         ft_sleep(void *vdata);                                                      //* sleep function
int         ft_think(void *vdata);                                                      //* think function


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    t_philo         philo;
    t_data          data[ft_atoi(argv[1])];
    pthread_t       philos[ft_atoi(argv[1])];
    pthread_t       monitoring;
    pthread_mutex_t forks[ft_atoi(argv[1])];
    int             i;

    i = 0;
    init_philo(&philo, argc, argv);
    while (i < philo.n_philo)
    {
        pthread_mutex_init(&forks[i], NULL);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while(i < philo.n_philo)
    {
        init_data(&data[i], &philo, i);
        data->left_fork = &forks[i];
        if (i == 0)
            data->right_fork = &forks[philo.n_philo - 1];
        else
            data->right_fork = &forks[i - 1];
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    philo.start_time = get_time();
    pthread_create(&monitoring, NULL, &monitor, &data);
    while (i < philo.n_philo)
    {
        pthread_create(&philos[i], NULL, &routine, &data[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < philo.n_philo)
    {
        pthread_join(philos[i], NULL);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&forks[i]);
        i++;
    }
    pthread_join(monitoring, NULL);
    return (0);
}

void    *monitor(void *vdata)
{
    t_data      *data;
    int         i;

    data = (t_data *)vdata;
    i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        while(i < data->philo->n_philo)
        {
            if (get_time() - data[i].last_eaten > (u_int64_t)data[i].philo->time_to_die && data[i].last_eaten != 0 && data[i].is_eating == 0)
            {
                printf("%llu %d died\n", get_time() - data->philo->start_time, data->id);
                data[i].dead = 1;
                exit(0);
            }
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
    }
    return (NULL);
}

void    *routine(void *vdata)
{
    t_data  *data;

    data = (t_data *)vdata;
    if (data->id % 2 == 0)
        ft_sleep(data);
    while (data->dead == 0)
    {
        ft_eat(data);
        ft_sleep(data);
        ft_think(data);
    }
    return (NULL);
}

int ft_sleep(void *vdata)
{
    time_t      strt;
    t_data      *data;

    data = (t_data *)vdata;
    strt = data->philo->start_time;
    printf("%llu %d is sleeping\n", get_time() - strt, data->id);
    ft_usleep(data->philo->time_to_sleep);
    return (0);
}

int ft_eat(void *vdata)
{
    time_t  strt;
    t_data  *data;

    data = (t_data *)vdata;
    strt = data->philo->start_time;
    pthread_mutex_lock(data->left_fork);
    printf("%llu %d has taken a fork\n", get_time() - strt, data->id);
    pthread_mutex_lock(data->right_fork);
    printf("%llu %d has taken a fork\n", get_time() - strt, data->id);
    data->is_eating = 1;
    printf("%llu %d is eating\n", get_time() - strt, data->id);
    ft_usleep(data->philo->time_to_eat);
    data->last_eaten = get_time();
    data->n_eat++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(data->left_fork);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(data->right_fork);
    data->is_eating = 0;
    return (0);
}

int ft_think(void *vdata)
{
    time_t  strt;
    t_data  *data;

    data = (t_data *)vdata;
    strt = data->philo->start_time;
    printf("%llu %d is thinking\n", get_time() - strt, data->id);
    return (0);
}

int ft_usleep(useconds_t time)
{
    time_t  start;
    start = get_time();
    while ((get_time() - start) < time)
        usleep(time / 10);
    return(0);
}

u_int64_t   get_time(void)
{
    struct timeval  tv;
    
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return ((tv.tv_sec * (u_int64_t)1000) + (tv.tv_usec / 1000));
}

void    init_philo(t_philo *philo, int argc, char **argv)
{
    philo->n_philo = ft_atoi(argv[1]);
    philo->time_to_die = ft_atoi(argv[2]);
    philo->time_to_eat = ft_atoi(argv[3]);
    philo->time_to_sleep = ft_atoi(argv[4]);
    if (argc == 6)
        philo->need_eat = ft_atoi(argv[5]);
    else
        philo->need_eat = -1;
    philo->start_time = get_time();
}

void    init_data(t_data *data, t_philo *philo, int id)
{
    
    data->id = id;
    data->last_eaten = 0;
    data->dead = 0;
    data->is_eating = 0;
    data->n_eat = 0;
    data->philo = philo;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. We can't compile it as it is right now

Comment: How do you call your program? You do not check if you have any command line argument. If you do not get any argument and pass a `NULL` pointer into `ft_atoi` you may get undefined behaviour if your hidden `ft_atoi` is somehow similar to common `atoi` function.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I added a reproducible example

Comment: @Gerhardh I was planning on verifying that later on. Currently tho even with arguments it seg fault (i call it like that `./philo 4 57 89 56 7`)

Comment: What is `u_int64_t`? Which header defines that? Why not `#include <stdint.h>` and use `uint64_t` instead? These are the errors I get with your current code: https://godbolt.org/z/TqWvqY989

Comment: looks for me as if your param vdata is not a t_data* but passed as a t_data**

Comment: @TedLyngmo u_int64_t is an unsigned long long. I don't know i saw that used somewhere and now i use it too, i didn't need to define it anywhere tho and i have no errors regarding this on my compiler

Comment: Ok. Is [Philosophers](https://github.com/TommyJD93/Philosophers) your repo? Anyway, I made a pull request to fix the compilation errors. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you, tho my repo is [this](https://github.com/yazukii/philo)

Comment: @yazukii Oh, I guess someone will get a surprise pull request :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo yep lol

Answer (score 2):

Given this definition:

> ```
>     t_data          data[ft_atoi(argv[1])];
> ```

, this does not initialize all your data:

> ```
>     i = 0;
>     while(i < philo.n_philo)
>     {
>         init_data(&data[i], &philo, i);
>         data->left_fork = &forks[i];
>         if (i == 0)
>             data->right_fork = &forks[philo.n_philo - 1];
>         else
>             data->right_fork = &forks[i - 1];
>         i++;
>     }
> ```

Variable `data` designates an array, so where it appears in the expressions above, it decays to a pointer to the first array element.  That is, you are repeatedly setting the forks of `data[0]`, and never setting those of the other elements.  That `i` does not appear in the expression `data`, and `data` itself is never modified, would have been your clue.

This is how that should be written:

```
    for (i = 0; i < philo.n_philo; i++) {  // prefer 'for' for simple iteration
        init_data(&data[i], &philo, i);
        data[i].left_fork = &forks[i];
        if (i == 0) {  // never omit braces around 'if' and 'else' bodies
            data[i].right_fork = &forks[philo.n_philo - 1];
        } else {
            data[i].right_fork = &forks[i - 1];
        }
    }
```

With that change, your program runs for me without segfaulting, and eventually terminates.

Comment: Oh. How could i not see this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer. I'm too lazy to debug your code. This is just a few comments in extended form.

---

You create a new thread to run `monitor()`, but your `main()` thread does nothing except wait while the `monitor` thread is running. Why create the thread? Why not just call `monitor()` from the main thread?

Too much information in comments: E.g., `int time_to_die;  //*time to die in ms`. You could convey the same information with `int time_to_die_ms;`

A better name for `t_philo` would be `t_parameters` or `t_configuration`. A better name for `t_data` would be `t_philosopher`. A better name for `routine()` would be `philosopher_main()`.

What's up with all of the `void*` parameters and all the type casts? The only place where you *need* `void*` is for the arguments of the thread functions, `monitor` and `routine`. Any other place where you want to pass a pointer to a `t_data` instance, the parameter should be declared to be of type `t_data*`.  E.g., `ft_eat(t_data* data)` instead of `ft_eat(void* vdata)`.

The `monitor()` thread and the `routine()` threads share access to `t_data` fields without any synchronization. That makes the behavior of your program officially "undefined."

The `monitor()` thread *spins:* It *continually* checks up on the philosophers as fast as it possibly can. That's using all of the available cycles of a whole CPU while potentially *starving* other threads. You don't need it to check so often. Maybe sleep for a second in the outer loop to give other threads a chance to do their thing.

Much confusion about milliseconds vs. microseconds in `ft_usleep()`. Looks like each time you call it, it will execute around ten thousand iterations of the loop, sleeping for `time/10000` milliseconds (`time/10` microseconds) in each iteration. If you like milliseconds, then use milliseconds everywhere except, *carefully and explicitly* when you call `usleep()`. Also, I'd get rid of the loop:*

```C
void ft_mssleep(int milliseconds) {
    useconds_t microseconds = (useconds_t)1000 * milliseconds;
    usleep(microseconds);
}
```

You've got functions declared to return `int` that always `return (0)`, and their callers never check the return value. Why are those functions not declared to return `void` instead?

This doesn't make any sense:

```C
    data[i].dead = 1;
    exit(0);
```

There's no point in setting the philosopher's `dead` flag if the very next thing you do is kill the whole program. Might as well just get rid of the `dead` flag altogether. If a philosopher "dies" because it's deadlocked, then it would never wake up to check the flag even if `monitor()` did *not* immediately kill the whole program.

---

* Was the loop because you were worried about overflow if the caller wanted to sleep for more than a few thousand seconds? That's probably over-thinking the requirements for this example, but if you *really* want to handle that case, then you'll maybe want to do something a bit more sophisticated than what you actually did.

Comment: Thank you for the advises. I'm gonna check all that